# Eclipse RCP: how do I get path to the ini file?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application, lets call it MyRcpApp. So, MyRcpApp will have MyRcpApp.ini file, near its launcher MyRcpApp.exe.

Question:
is it possible to get full path to ini file (like C:\work\MyRcpAppExported\eclipse\MyRcpApp.ini) from inside java code of MyRcpApp?

Thanks in advance,
Sergey

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick for you:

```
URL url = new URL(Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL()+Platform.getProduct().getName()+".ini");
```

Then just use the url to get at the file contents.

Comment: Except if you're on Mac. On Mac, the ini file is inside the youappname.app. `String spec = Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL()
    + Platform.getProduct().getName() + ".ini";
    if (Util.isMac()) {
   spec = Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL()
     + Platform.getProduct().getName() + ".app/Contents/MacOS/"
     + Platform.getProduct().getName() + ".ini";
  }
  URL url = new URL(spec);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, except you have changed the launcher ini file path to something different, for sure, using the "--launcher.ini {Path}" command line option. So this question isn't answered already, I'd say.

https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html